# Can Visual Studio detect http requests and rebuild automatically when running web application with Start Without Debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I'm reading "Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2" by Adam Freedman. In the book Freedmans writes the following about using "Start Without Debugging" in Visual Studio:

*"The classes in the project are compiled automatically when an HTTP request is received, allowing for a more dynamic development experience".*

He then goes on to give an example where he runs a simple website using Debug → Start Without Debugging. He does a change in a controller (not a Razor view), refreshes the browser and is then able to see the change in the browser.

I cannot get this to work. If I try the same, I always have to select "Start Without Debugging" again to get Visual Studio to rebuild the code.

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 Preview.

I'm not able to find any information online about this feature either, so I'm not sure if it is specific to dotnet core or is supposed to work with .NET in general.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get it to work, I just had to use IIS Express instead of Kestrel. Now the question remains whether this only works on dotnet core.